# Why using to template type with some type traits causes template deduction failure

Tags: c++, templates, type-deduction

I have this simple case:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
struct Handle_ {
    T vlue;
};

template<typename T>
using Handle = Handle_<std::enable_if_t<true, T>>;

template<typename T>
void fooo(Handle<T> h, int a) {
}

int main() {
    Handle<int> a;

    fooo(a, 4);
}
```

Which does not compile, because template argument deduction for `fooo` failed.
If from `Handle` using `std::enable_if_t` is removed - it works.

```
template<typename T>
using Handle = Handle_<T>;
```

What is a reason that creating some dependency in this using makes it not deducible?

Answer (score 1):

This is because `std::enable_if_t` is an alias to

```
template< bool B, class T = void >
using enable_if_t = typename enable_if<B,T>::type;
```

Thus `T` is in the left of `::`, which is a [non-deduced context](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Non-deduced_contexts).

Also note an alias will be treated as its aliased template. [An alias *itself* won't participate in deduction](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.alias#2).